# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. C#

Tags: c#, webclient, internal-server-error

I have a question. I have a small program that calls a web service using a API Key. Whenever I execute my code I get the follow error

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Visual Studio 2012 stopped indicating me into the follow line

```
myHttpWResp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myHttpWReq.GetResponse();
```

Do you know what it can be causing this?

Comment: The Web Service is erroring.  Something is breaking internally. That's what HTTP 500 is telling you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you think its my url? or something is the code?

Comment: @user3790916, It is the remote web service you are calling that is throwing an error, it is possible that you are not calling it in the right way but if it throws an error because of this then it is a badly written web service.

Comment: Hi, do you mind if I post my code here and you can help me to see what I can be doing wrong?

Comment: I have change from Post method to get (myHttpWReq.Method = "Get";) and I have this line (//myHttpWReq.ContentLength = 0;) now I dont get wny message but it doesnt display anything

Answer (score 0):

Attach the debugger to the web server. The debugger should break when the error occurs.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have change the post method to get (myHttpWReq.Method = "Get";) and I have this line (//myHttpWReq.ContentLength = 0;) and when I execute the code I am not getting any error now but its doesnt display anything